# SSRS 2008 R2 creating random blank pages on report?

Tags: reporting-services

hoping someone can help.

my report in SSRS 2008 R2 is randomly creating a blank page on the rendered report (and when it's exported to Word).  I've investigated it here and Google and tried everything that's been suggested.

My Page Setup under Report Properties is Letter (portrait) 8.5in x 11in, with 0 for all 4 of the margins (I've tried using .25in for all 4, same results).

the size of the body, etc. on the report is 8in x 3.3094 -- nothing is over 8in in width.

"Keep together on one page if possible" is unchecked for all the elements on the report (Lists, tables, body).  It produces the same result if it is checked, too.

The ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace on the report is set to TRUE.

Again, when it's rendered on the web browser, I have 6 pages that are fine, then a blank, then several more single pages, then another blank.

Oddy enough, when I view it (on the development machine, not on the web) in PRINT mode, there are no blank pages at all (which is good).

can anyone help?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like some element is just over the edge of the margin and is creating that blank page. Since it doesn't appear after every page is there any common element that is present on the page before the blank ones that might be near the edge?

I think the HTML renderer must have slightly different margins (or something) when compared to the print renderer in SSDT. Unfortunately for these kinds of issues in SSRS the best way to solve it is to go through all of the possible offending report elements and make sure that they aren't going over the edge.

I'd recommend just moving EVERYTHING away from the right margin and seeing if it fixes it, and then moving things back one by one to figure out where the problem is. Either that or you can make the report margins smaller and see if that fixes it. Even if you need to revert them afterwards and still find the offending element, it could be a good way to test what the problem is.

This could also be caused by an element in the report having the "Insert Page Break Before/After" option enabled. You should check the elements that appear before/after the page break to ensure that option is not set. However, since the issue doesn't happen in all rendering modes I don't think this is the most likely issue.

Comment: hi @mike d., thanks for your help.  I'm going to try moving everything over, I've already tried setting the margin to 0 for all and I still get the blanks....

Comment: moving everything over didn't help and I can't see anything different between one that doesn't have a blank page after and one that does.  I did have "insert page break after" selected for the  table on the report, I turned it off but still the same resuts....ARHG....

Comment: I did see it, and just now tried it -- changed the report properties to centimeters, then back to inches and still getting a blank page.  I am tearing my hair out!  ARGH.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I clicked on the down arrow on the Row Group, picked Group Properties, and unchecked the Page Break Options/Between Each Instance of a Group and there's no more blank pages :)

thanks for everyone's help!